# Cannot get SKProductsResponse products: response.count = 0

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, product

I've just added iAP in my app and i get an error.

```
- (void)getProductID { //runs on viewdidload
    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
        SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects:_productID, nil]];
        request.delegate = self;

        [request start];
    } else {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Serpentine" message:@"Error: Could not connect to store. Try enabling in-app-purchases in settings." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];

        [self couldNotConnectToStore];
    }

}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:[self unlockPurchase];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:NSLog(@"Transation Failed");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

            default:break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    NSArray *products = response.products;

    if (products.count != 0) {
        _product = products[0];
        _allowPurchase = YES;
    } else {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Serpentine" message:@"Error: Could not connect to store" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];//this line of code runs a second after the controller opens

//****************** error on line above *********************************

        [self couldNotConnectToStore];
    }

    products = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;

    for (SKProduct *product in products) {
        NSLog(@"Product not found: %@", product);
    }
}


- (IBAction)purchaseButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (sender.tag == 1) {
        //buy 20
        _productID = @"com.piguygames.serpentine.buy20";

        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:_product];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

    } else if (sender.tag == 2) {
        //buy 45
    } else if (sender.tag == 3) {
        //buy 100
    } else if (sender.tag == 4) {
        //double
    } else if (sender.tag == 5) {
        //remove ads
    }
}
```

Note: there is some other code in the controller, but i don't think it is relevant.

I have added the in app purchase to iTunes connect and it says "ready to submit". So should it be fine here? Also I got a warning on that same site saying that I must submit a new version of my app to get in app purchases working. I decided I would submit my app and disable the iAP in the app first, then release the iAP in a later update. Do you need to submit a new version to test the iAP?

Anyway, are there any problems you can see so far?

Please do ask for more information if there is more needed, I am a beginner with this topic.
Thanks

Comment: I have to go to bed now, if there are any questions ill be able to answer them in around 10 hours. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure _productID you are passing to initWithProductIdentifiers: is not nil ?

Comment: Are you using your test account in your process ? You should - if not create one in iTunes connect. On your normal account it's not gonna work.

Comment: I'm logged out, but I made a test account. Also i think _productID is nil. I'll make a change now

Comment: even when it isn't nil i still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you're signed out of any iTunes account in the Settings app, unless it's a test account you created in iTunes Connect. I recently had this exact same problem and that's how I solved it.

Comment: I was signed out, and i had made a test account, but the test account is asking me to do the normal sign up for stuff on the app store

Comment: What is this sandbox mode I keep hearing about? How do I enable it?

Comment: You don't have to enable the Sandbox environment. Just logout from the app store & then after run your application, when it ask for the credential use the test account credentials.
For the Signup stuff please try to create test user of US country & then try. Hope it helps you!!!

Comment: If your test account is asking you to do the normal sign up then you've rendered it useless for testing. You'll need to create a new test account.

Comment: What could I have done wrong? it asked me to sign up when i logged in in iPad settings btw.

Comment: You can't sign in through the Settings or you invalidate the test account. You can only sign in when the app asks you to perform a purchase in the Sandbox environment. See the 'Testing Your In-App Purchases' section in: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/13_ManagingIn-AppPurchases/ManagingIn-AppPurchases.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH4-SW1